# CSS - Chrome/Safari same font-weight not applying when uploading to Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face, font-size

I have a front-end site which I'm uploading to Wordpress using a HTML5 Blank child theme. There are quite distinctive differences in font-weights on some hover text - and also in the footer - which I wasn't seeing in the standalone front-end version.

**Example - Footer**

[image: Wordpress]

[image: non-Wordpress]

**Example - Hover text**

[image: Wordpress]

[image: Front-end]

This is what I have in my styles -

**style.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamLight';
    src: url('fonts/GothamLight.eot');
    src: url('fonts/GothamLight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/GothamLight.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/GothamLight.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/GothamLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/GothamLight.otf') format('opentype'),
         url('fonts/GothamLight.svg#GothamLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body {

    font-family: 'GothamLight', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased !important;

}
```

I've trawled google and SO looking for answers - I've tried them all but none appear to work. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

specify a font face for every font weight you want to use:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'GothamLight';
src: url('fonts/GothamLight.eot');
src: url('fonts/GothamLight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/GothamLight.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/GothamLight.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/GothamLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/GothamLight.otf') format('opentype'),
     url('fonts/GothamLight.svg#GothamLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'GothamLight';
src: url('path/to/weight500font');
src: url('path/to/weight500font') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('path/to/weight500font') format('woff2'),
     url('path/to/weight500font') format('woff'),
     url('path/to/weight500font') format('truetype'),
     url('path/to/weight500font') format('opentype'),
     url('path/to/weight500font') format('svg');
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is to do with the confusion of weights you have within your CSS, combined with the `webkit-font-smoothing`. A "light" font is typically 300 weight, which you are then trying to render at a 500 weight. I can imagine many browsers are "faux bolding" the font. I suspect Wordpress has some font-smoothing/weight overrides in place.

I would recommend removing your `font-weight: 500` and `webkit-font-smoothing` attributes and starting from there. If you want a 500 weight font, I would also recommend finding the 500 weight of Gotham - if it exists. If not, I would advise against trying to force the browser using it!